# 403 forbidden when calling Graph API from Postman but works fine from Graph Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, postman, azure-app-registration

My aim is to get an application to interact with Azure Connectors.
At the moment, I'm focusing on getting working connections before I dive into the actual code.

I am trying to get `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/external/connections` to work. ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/externalconnectors-externalconnection-list?view=graph-rest-1.0))

On a test Azure tenant, I've set up an app registration for Single-page application allowing me to use the implicit OAuth 2.0 authentication flow.
(Grants access tokens, not ID tokens, and I've allowed public client flows just in case)

Note that the simple get user request (no special permissions needed) works fine from Postman with this setup. (`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`)

However, when I got to the actual connectors request, things stopped working. I set up Delegated permissions for `ExternalConnection.Read.All`. **This permission is enough to get the request to work on Graph Explorer**, but now I am getting 403 forbidden responses on Postman when the request is sent out (**not the authentication request, which works fine** and returns an access token).
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried adding application permissions on top of delegated permissions, to no avail.

I would like to keep the implicit flow if possible, I am just surprised by how difficult this is.

Comment: Can reproduce the same behavior, but the issue is related only to external/connections endpoint and related delegated permission. All other endpoints work fine (with the correct permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As mentioned in this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#prefer-the-auth-code-flow), with the plans for removing third party cookies from browsers, the **implicit grant flow is no longer a suitable authentication method**.

I registered one Single-page application and granted same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I tried to fetch the external connections by generating token using **implicit** flow, I too got **same error**:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/external/connections
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I used **Authorization Code(With PKCE)** flow for generating access token via Postman and got the **response** successfully:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/external/connections
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to include **`Origin`** header while generating token with *Authorization code(with PKCE)* flow for **Single-page** application:

```http
Origin: <your redirect URL>
```

[image]

You can also use **client credentials** flow by granting permission of `Application` type and use it for fetching list of external connections like this:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/external/connections
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer, this worked very well ! (First had to get a hang of the authorization code flow, but got there in the end)
As stated by @user2250152, other requests work fine with the implicit flow, do you happen to know why this one doesn't ?